# html script ,how to set time interval before redirecting to another webpage

Tags: javascript, html

i want to set pause 5 seconds  to display a loading gif image before it direct to webpage 
btw im using iframe and direct it to parent window
how can i set that? please be gentle guys im kinda newbie on scripts thanks :D

```
<html>
<script>
 window.parent.location = "https://www.google.com"
</script>

<center>
  <img src=progress_bar.gif>
</center>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this in you script area:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.parent.location = "https://www.google.com"
},5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use setTimeout like below to achieve what you want to.

```
setTimeout(function(){
window.parent.location = "https://www.google.com"
},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout :

```
 setTimeout(function(){
    window.parent.location = "https://www.google.com";
 }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a meta-refresh-tag is working for you?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://webdesign.about.com/">
```

The `2` means, that the site is redirected after 2 seconds.

Comment: tnx but im using iframe to redirect to parent window

Answer (score 0):

Look at [javascript setTimeout](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout)

It will look like:
`setTimeout('window.parent.location = "https://www.google.com"', 5000);`

Comment: I think you have to put the redirect-code into a "`function(){ .. code here ..}`", otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: I understand that that's not very readable and useful, but under link I attached is example with `alert()` looks the same